# Rewrite URL only wothout redirecting the page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress site installed on a domain, inside a subfolder. Now my client wants to show it as the default page, but I don't know how to do it without reinstalling WP to the root directory of the server.

I simply want to rewrite to URL of mysite.com/wp to mysite.com, and other subfolderls like mysite.com/wp/a-wordpress-page to mysite.com/a-wordpress-page

What I've tried so far:

- Placed an index.php to the root with header redirect, but it will rewrite the URL to /wp
- Including the /wp/index.php to the main index.php. It works when you open the page, but after following any link on the site, the /wp/ part will show up again.
- Tried some RewriteRules in .htaccess but can't figure out how to do it correctly.

So what is the easiest solution to do it with .htaccess or PHP?

Comment: The best way to do this is by using rewrite rules. You can find the mod_rewrite documentation here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/rewrite/intro.html.

Comment: At best you first try to follow wordpress documentation about this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: Thanks @Zimmi! You solved my problem, and maybe it's the best and easiest way for WordPress sites.